# Byte Array printing negative values. Want to print same value as positive

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android. I have byte array of size 10. I am passing the Decimal values (131 – 140) to byte array. But while printing I get Negative (-) values with decreasing order  .

How can I get same value as positive values?

Please need help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well show how you pass them. And how you print them.

Answer (score 3):

If you want positive values, use `short` array or `int` array. The `byte` type in Java is signed, so the max positive value is 127.

Comment: to be precise java doesn't have unsigned type

Comment: @Blackbelt That's not precise. Not all primitive types in Java are signed. `char` is unsigned.

Comment: fair enough, but char is meant for text.. still you are right

Comment: Thanks for comments friends, but i need is i have value greater than 127

Comment: i mean values from 128 to 255

Comment: @user3206384 Then use a type that can hold values higher than 127 (short, int or long).

Comment: or can i get hex or decimal values for same? but is Byte Array only